Button "OPEN" WebApp next to the bot in Telegram chats

How to create an "OPEN" button using PHP, next to the bot in the Telegram chat list?
Or what is the function called?
if ($param === 'webapp') {
    $replyMarkup = [
        'inline_keyboard' => [
            [
                [
                    'text' => 'ОТКРЫТЬ',
                    'web_app' => ['url' => 'https://домен.com/webapp']
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ];

This code opens the WebApp inside the bot, but how can I display the button in the general chat list?

StackOverflow is an [English-only site]. Please either rewrite your question in English or refer to [ru.so].
